# How do I provide default values to optional nested props of type Object in typescript + React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using Typescript and React. I typically assign default props while destructuring them like so:

```
import * as React from "react"

type ComponentProps = {
  a: string;
  b?: number;
}

const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({
  a,
  b = 2
}) => {

  //...

}
```

But if a prop is an object, or even a nested object, is there a way to assign default values to some properties while keeping some as required?

For example:

```
import * as React from "react"

type ComponentProps = {
  a: {
    b: number;
    c?: string;
  };
  d?: {
    e?: number;
    f?: string;
  };
  g?: {
    h?: number;
    f: string;
  };
}

const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({

  /* I'm not sure what to do here...*/

}) => {
  //...
}
```

I guess I'm actually asking three questions.

1. While destructuring, can I assign a default value to the optional property of a required object, such as a.c ?
2. While destructuring, if I assign default values to d.e and d.f, and when used only d.e is provided, will d.f still be retained?
3. Can you have a required property of an optional object, such as g.f ? I think in my mind it's like saying, "This prop is optional, but if you provide it you ***must*** provide g.f ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *possible*, but nested destructuring can be difficult to read. I'd recommend avoiding the pattern when possible.

> While destructuring, can I assign a default value to the optional property of a required object, such as a.c ?

If you had to, for a default value for `c`:

```
const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({
  a: {
    b,
    c = 'foo',
  }
  // ...
}) => {
  //...
}
```

> While destructuring, if I assign default values to d.e and d.f, and when used only d.e is provided, will d.f still be retained?

Yes, if you assign a default object to the whole `d`:

```
const Component = ({
  d: {
    e = 5,
    f = 'foo',
  } = {},
}: ComponentProps) => {
  //...
}
```

> Can you have a required property of an optional object, such as g.f

Yes, that's just fine.

Comment: I've mainly been using object default values due to [this document](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/default_props/). So I suppose I should transition to using defaultProps, eh?

Comment: Object default values work fine, and since `defaultProps` is going to be deprecated, I wouldn't use `defaultProps`.